# Leaflet repeats map online

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've created an interactive map using leaflet and its working fine using xampp on my localhost. Today I registered a domain and uploaded everything to a webspace and suddenly the map starts repeating itself on the x-axis for half it its size on the left side before the 'real' map starts.
For the purpose of testing I changed my map-image to an empty grid.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xqH9.jpg "Uploaded content (60 columns)"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdJo6.jpg "Local content using xampp (40 columns)"

The image size is 4096x4096 and is loaded as follows:

```
var mapSW = [0, 4096],
    mapNE = [4096, 0];
var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0],1);
L.tileLayer('maps/emptyGrid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  minZoom: 1,
  maxZoom: 4,
  continousWorld: false,
  noWrap:true,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
}).addTo(map)

map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(
  map.unproject(mapSW, map.getMaxZoom()),
  map.unproject(mapNE, map.getMaxZoom())
  ));
```

Comment: I fixed the issue myself by downgrading the leaflet version from 1.4.0 to 0.7.7

Comment: I would say you didn't properly load the leaflet css file